# Context wants FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK but I've already set that flag

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-sdk-2.3

I've created a common re-usable class for the company I work for to create some common interface elements.

The class, takes in a single parameter as in the construct: an application context.

one of the methods, `ContentClickableRowWithIcon` allows you to pass in an intent to be used as the click action.

heres the full method declaration:

`public LinearLayout ContentClickableRowWithIcon(Drawable icon, String title, Intent i, final Boolean chooser)`

that last attribute there is used in the onClickEvent to determine whether to invoke a Chooser or just go right into the intent.

```
public LinearLayout ContentClickableRowWithIcon(Drawable icon, String title, Intent i, final Boolean chooser) {

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);

    // ..  LinerLayout construction, has nothing to do with the action

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // this is apparently getting ignored... (ps: i've tried i.setFlags as well)

    final Intent intent = i;

    ll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(chooser)
                mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete With...")); // crashes here with: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
            else
                mContext.startActivity(intent); // this works fine

        }
    });

    return ll;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, anytime I dont provide the ability to use a chooser, everything works fine (everything in this list gets a new activity flag, im well aware of this and will cleanup when this issue is figured out)

The moment I do, throws the exception:
`android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?`

I've run out of ideas...

/// EDIT:: Worth noting, on debug, the flags attribute in the Intent is set to `268435456` with addFlags and `268435456` with setFlags, when it reaches the time to use the intent in the onClick action

Comment: have u tried `mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Complete With..."));` ?

Comment: My guess would be that the new Intent returned by createChooser() does not have the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK set. Try getting the intent, setting the flag, then calling startActivity

Comment: aside from the fact that i needs to be final'd anyways? When I do that (set in the paramters `final Intent i`, the flags never get set at all, flags = 0 in the debug

Comment: just did this: `if(chooser) {
     Intent intent = i;
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete With..."));
    }` in leu, still crashed :\

Comment: try this: `Intent newIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete With...");
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(newIntent);`

Comment: hmm intesting @Clyde as it doesn't crash anymore, come sup with the chooser, but doesn't populate the list.... very interesting ok i.. THINK i can work with this...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Problem has been fixed, I think this is simply the case of an "order of operation" scenario

heres what allowed this thing to work:

```
    ll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {



            if(chooser) {
                Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Complete With");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            } else
                mContext.startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

also added a "final" modifier to the parameter in the method declaration

```
public LinearLayout ContentClickableRowWithIcon(Drawable icon, String title, final Intent i, final Boolean chooser)
```

Comment: Not "order of operation" exactly but the fact that createChooser returns a new Intent. The flag you set in the original intent is not copied to the new one automatically.

Comment: +10 (well, if I could anyway).  I've been pulling my hair out over this one.  The breakthrough is in understand that there are actually *two* intents involved.  I was setting the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK on the wrong intent.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Good to know the "two intent" stuff. haha

Comment: Any assistance with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071016/how-to-share-by-clicking-on-an-element-inside-the-card-array-adapter will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I need to set the flag on the intent not the context, as the error message suggests. Good to know..

Answer (score 1):

Actually your exception mean that you are using Not Activity Context. it could be called from Application context. Check that you are in Activity context since this is not a service

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it adding the flag to the Chooser Intent

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            .setType("text/plain")
            .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here")
            .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share with").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```