# Context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag but I've already set flag

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to launch e-mail application using `Intent` from outside activity context and I've already set the flag.

Any suggestions?

```
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            try {
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.setType("message/rfc822");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{addressList[position]});
                aContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) 

            }
        }
```

here's error:

[image]

Comment: Context context = MyApplication.this.getApplicationContext();

Comment: Try setting the flag after putting the extra? (Why are you setting the flag twice, by the way?)

Comment: Please post your error in text instead of images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail...")` returns a new intent, not your original `i`.

Set the flag on the intent returned by `Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail...")`

```
   Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail...");
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   aContext.startActivity(intent);
```

More info about this issue: [Context wants FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK but I've already set that flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529492/context-wants-flag-activity-new-task-but-ive-already-set-that-flag)